# Deleting rows in Excel with specific combination of values using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I want to insert some code into an existing macro that deletes all rows except those with a specific combination of values in columns O and P. The combinations are in I3:I13 and J3:13.

In other words, I want to keep rows that in columns O and P have values corresponding to I3 and J3 respectively, or I6 and J6 respectively, etc, and delete all the others.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit with an example of the data that needs to match, also providing your existing macro could be useful.

Comment: You realize, of course, that you may delete rows **3** through **13** and thus destroy the criteria ??

Answer (score 0):

Far from perfect but without sample data I assumed a few things.

```
Sub deleteRow()

Dim lastRow As Integer, matchVal As String, searchVal As String

lastRow = Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 3 Step -1
    matchVal = Cells(i, 9).Value & " " & Cells(i, 10).Value
    searchVal = Cells(i, 15).Value & " " & Cells(i, 16).Value
    If matchVal <> searchVal Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i

MsgBox "Next time I will add an example to my question"
End Sub
```

If values in I and J do not equal values in O and P the line will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim col1 As Long
Dim col2 As Long
Dim count As Long

col1 = Range("I:I").column
col2 = Range("J:J").column
count = ActiveSheet.Range("I3").End(xlDown).row

For i = count To 3 Step -1
    If Cells(i, col1) <> Cells(i, col1).Offset(0, 6) Or Cells(i, col2) <> Cells(i, col2).Offset(0, 6) Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I never advise using `End(xlDown)` to find the final row. If there is no data in the sheet this would run for a million rows.

Comment: @Tim Wilkinson True. What you have or `cells(rows.Count,col1).end(xlup).row` would be better. Thanks!